# Show that Eigenspace is invariant under flow in gradient vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, invariance

I'm struggling with where to start on the following question

> Consider the gradient vector field
>
> $$ \frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
>  \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}
>  \end{pmatrix} $$
>   where $V(x,y)=x^3y+xy^3-4xy$.
>   Show that $(0,0)+E_{\lambda}$ for the two eigenspaces $E_{\lambda}$ of $D^2V(0,0)$ is invariant under the flow.

I don't really know where to start. What is $D^2V(0,0)$? The Jacobi matrix?

Phase plane:
[image]

I have calculated the Jacobi matrix:
$$
J(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
6xy && 3x^2+3y^2-4 \\
3x^2+3y^2-4 && 6xy
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I found that $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium point: an (instable) saddle point. I then found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $J(0,0)$: $\lambda_1=4, \eta_1=(1,-1)^t, \lambda_2=-4, \eta_2=(1,1)^t$.

So then $(0,0) + E_{\lambda_1}=E_{\lambda_1}= \{(1, -1)^t\}$ and $E_{\lambda_2}=\{(1, 1)^t\}$.

Then I'm stuck, mostly because I don't know what they mean. Invariant under what flow? And is $D^2V(0,0)$ what I assumed above?

Comment: I think perhaps you intended $V(x, y) = x^3y + xy^3 - 4xy$ rather than $V(x, y) = x^3y - xy^3 - 4xy$ in the 4th line of your post.  Could I be correct?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, though I typed an $=$ instead of the $-$. I corrected it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: @RobertLewis I think I came up with an answer, but I'm not sure, what should I do?

Comment: Well, you can answer your own question, or you can edit your post to include your answer (in which case you might want to say you're interested in other approaches as well), or you can do nothing.  Looking forward to seeing what you've got.  By the way, I'll probably post pretty soon myself.

Comment: @RobertLewis If it's different from your answer, I'll post it and hopefully you'll check if it is correct. Will  be somewhere tomorrow.

Comment: Be glad to look it over!